# Monitor activemq topic

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am beginner in ActiveMQ, so I got some question... I'm going to make client-server application, uses activemq on server side. All clients send messages, so there is single queue on server receiving messages from all clients. It is not a problem, as I understand.

But there is another thing... After receiving message, server works with it and forms the answer message for EACH incoming message, and this message must be delivered for ALL clients, not only for sender. And if there is no connection to some client at the moment, when connection recovered, client must receive all messages server sent during the time this client was off-line (with no loss).

Starting learn ActiveMQ, I found solution: there is a certain number of "output queues" on server, and this number equal to the number of clients. So, after forming the answer, server application goes through all "output queues", and puts the message in each queue. In this variant, EACH client has unique ID and listen its OWN queue (with ALL answer messages), so on server we can monitor, which number of messages each client received (it is advantage). But also, I think, it's not the best solution (a lot of identical objects in queues + manually adding each client on server side are downsides).

Learning more about activemq, I found Topics and durable Subscribers. Looks like something I need for problem described. But now my question is - how can I monitor Topic messages? I tried watch it in a browser administrator tool, also in jconsole, but I can't see this messages yet. Is it possible? And any questions for the future - is using topics a good idea for this problem? Or may be better to use certain number of output queues, as I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durable subscriptions is probably the way to go. But, as you have experienced, you need to sacrifice a bit of operational transparency.

You might want to have a look at virtual destinations as well which can potentially solve your issues.

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations